# Java/Java EE - Deploying application servers from different vendors in a single environment

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, weblogic

I have several applications running under Tomcat and some applications running on WebLogic. I need to bring them all together under a single domain and also share the static resources among all applications.

I am thinking of using the Apache web server as a front controller and use the WebLogic proxy plugin to route requests to applications running on WebLogic and Tomcat plugin to route requests to applications running on Tomcat.

Is there any disadvantage to this approach? Or is there any other better solution?

Comment: You should choose one 'leading' application server, which referes to the others.

Comment: Can you please explain more, what all static resources you are looking to share ?

Comment: images, help, video based content, flash files to name some of them.

Answer (score -1):

I'd :

put shared resources to a predefined NFS, defined in & accessed from both app servers

set caching on and serve static content from apache

distribute applications among physical servers based on their memory and cpu requirements